# Problem with open app Skype, iMessage, WhatsApp after click url on website?

Tags: android, html, ios, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner web developer. I have website.
I have url:

```
- Skype - <a href ="skype:600000000">Skype me</a>
- Call - <a href ="tel:600000000">Call me by phone</a>
- iMessage - <a href ="tel:600000000">Send me message by iMessage</a>
- Whatsapp - <a href ="whatsapp://name">Send me message by Whatsapp </a>
```

I need after clicking Skype - call the selected number from the Skype application. After clicking WhatsApp / iMessage - open and write a message to the selected number from WhatsApp / iMessage.

How to do it
At the moment applications are opening, but they are not dialing the right number

How can I repair it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to follow the [Skype URI tutorial: iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuritutorial_iosapps) and [WhatsApp API](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013).

For Apple's API you will need [Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) and [SMS Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html)